# Workflow to send a List?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

I have a Birthday List, and I need to write a workflow to send a list of those who meet years two days in advance, and send an email to those who fulfill years on the day of.

Comment: What version of SharePoint

Comment: Sharepoint 2013

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SharePoint 2013, you can write a workflow that iterates through the entire list. So you could add everyone who meets the requirements to a list, send the list out 2 days in advance, then send it to each person meeting the requirements on the day of. Search the web for how to write a 2013 SharePoint Designer workflow, how to iterate through an entire list, and how to send emails.

Comment: I know how to send emails from an ebb and flow as well as writing. When I'm in the mail editor, within the flow not to add fields to leave my list in the mail ..
oh well, displaying a view as filtrafa with a condition.